# Find/change in FrameMaker does not recognize linked words

Tags: framemaker

I want FrameMaker 2015 make sure that the first instance of every abbreviation/acronym is linked to the glossary. When I search it will skip over any abbreviation/acronym that I have already linked.

How can I make FrameMaker recognize an abbreviation/acronym even if it is already linked?

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the **Glossary** topic in FrameMaker help and follow their recommendation to use *Markers* to define glossary terms.
2. Follow the instructions in the **Markers** topic to generate a list of glossary markers.
3. Follow the instructions in the **Search** topic to find each glossary marker in the body text.
4. Use the Find/Edit feature to verify that each glossary marker for a specific term precedes other non-glossary marker instances of the term.